# Write a geometric series if $r = 1/6$ and $n = 8$.

Tags: geometric-series

Write a geometric series if $r = 1/6$ and $n = 8$.

I tried using the formula $a_n = a_1r^{n-1}$ and $S_n = a_1\cfrac{(1-r^n)}{1-r}$ but I don't know how to find the values for the terms like $a_1$.

Comment: You choose a value for $a_1$. Doesn't matter which one. Take your favourite number in the whole, wide world, and go for it.

Comment: What does $n$ stand for?

Comment: Did you mean $a_1=8?$

Comment: What is the problem ? If you insert $r$ and $n$ you get a formula depending on $a_1$.

Answer (score 1):

You can take $a_1$ whatever you like and then proceed by multiplying it with the common ratio $\frac 1 6$ successively until you reach at the $8$-th term.